# Choosing which dictionary to use based on user input in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to solve an issue in order to be able to teach some skills to my GCSE class this is based on the idea of a currency converter.  I have a program that allows me to convert from a single currency using a dictionary to chose the exchange rate based on the currency you want to be converted to.

I have tried to extend this using multiple dictionaries but am unable to get the code to select which dictionary to used based on the user input.

My commented code is below - basically I want to chose which dictionary to use based on the user input for the currency in the first while loop.

```
GBP={"USD":1.64,"EUR":1.21,"YEN":171.63}
USD={"GBP":0.61,"EUR":0.73,"YEN":104.27}
EUR={"GBP":0.83,"USD":1.36,"YEN":141.79}
currencyList=("GBP","EUR","USD","YEN")
#Sets up the dictonaries of conversion rates and validation list for acceptable currencies

while True:
    rate=input("What currency do you require to convert to?\n")
    if rate in GBP:
        #####This is where I have the issue - this code currently works but only for converting from GBP (using the GBP dictonary),
        #####I want to change the 'GBP' to use whatever dictonary corresponds to the value entered for currency
        #####in the loop above.
```

Comment: Please don't self-vandalise your post. You just made the whole answer I gave worthless. You licensed the post as CC-Wiki to Stack Overflow so others could learn from it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to map to variable names. Just create another level here, add a dictionary holding your currencies:

```
currencies = {
    'GBP': {"USD":1.64,"EUR":1.21,"YEN":171.63},
    'USD': {"GBP":0.61,"EUR":0.73,"YEN":104.27},
    'EUR': {"GBP":0.83,"USD":1.36,"YEN":141.79},
}
```

You can then take the keys of the dictionary to make a list of available currencies:

```
print(list(currencies))
```

and you can test if the currency exists:

```
if currency in currencies:
```

Once a currency is picked, use `currencies[currency]` to refer to the nested dictionary.

Comment: This is O(n^2) in memory consumption.  It might be simpler to just have a canonical currency and convert everything through that.

Comment: @Kevin: sure, but that's a future step. Also, the input map allows conversions to YEN but not vice-versa, that could be a valid restriction.

Comment: Thanks again that's exactly what I was looking for but my newbie searches for dictionaries in dictionaries didn't turn up anything!

@Martijin, well spotted I was doing this as a demo and got bored researching and typing in all the exchange rates!

Comment: @Kevin, could you explain what you mean by canonical currency?

Comment: @TheRegisSchoolICTDepartmen: set all the exchange rates relative to dollars. If you have to convert between two currencies A and B, convert A to dollars first, then dollars to B. Dollars is then a canonical currency.